# How are chakra/kosha/dosha/gunas/etc ontologically compatible?

Tags: science

There are seemingly endless spiritual ideas incorporated into Hinduism - ideas like kosha, gunas, dosha, chakras, etc. These frameworks don't seem to have a unified ontology or single scriptural origin.  How can they be unified or understood holistically?